# How to sort based on different nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to sort my tags in a XML file based on multiple different nodes.
For example:
Consider the following XML:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>12</b>
        <e>hello</e>
    </a> 
    <a>
        <b>11</b>
        <e>how</e>
    </a>
    <a>
        <c>13</c>
        <f>are</f>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>21</b>
        <f>you</f>
    </a>
    <a>
        <d>22</d>
        <e>hello</e>
    </a>
    <a>
        <c>14</c>
        <f>hi</f>
    </a>
</root>
```

Now I need to find the maximum number from inside all the nodes inside `a`.
I tried doing this:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="a">
        <xsl:sort select="b | c | d" data-type="number" order="descending"/>   <!-- this gives me error-->
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <!-- how to access my node -->
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I do my sorting and get the value form the first node after sorting?

Thnx in advance!!

**Note:** I am using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: what is your required output? Please see my answer below. Should you have a different requirement, feel free to edit your post.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen structure of the output is not important. I just need the maximum value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each select="a/*[string(number(.))!='NaN']">
            <xsl:sort select="." order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <highest><xsl:copy-of select="."/></highest>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the edited input XML above, outputs

```
<highest>
   <d>22</d>
</highest>
```

Comment: plz see the updated XML. The nodes inside `a` may not always be nodes containing numbers. Other types of node may also be present.

Comment: I have edited my post. Please check if this suits your requirement.

Comment: yes, after tweaking the idea a little according to my XML I can use your solution. thank you very much.

Comment: what if i have to process the numbers before sorting them. For example, in the above xml the numbers had some units associated with them like `m`, `cm`, `in` etc. Now first I have to transform all of them in a single unit like `cm` and then sort them. How can I do that?

Comment: please post this as another question.

Comment: plz find the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660086/xslt-how-to-process-on-values-before-sorting-them