# How to process on values before sorting them?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I previously posted [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602178/how-to-sort-based-on-different-nodes) on this portal for which I got a satisfactory solution. Now my problem has evolved a bit. What if my XML in the linked question is updated so that my numbers have a unit associated with them like `cm`, `m`, `in`, `px` etc. So that the new XML is:

```
<root>
<a>
    <b>12cm</b>
    <e>hello</e>
</a> 
<a>
    <b>11m</b>
    <e>how</e>
</a>
<a>
    <c>13m</c>
    <f>are</f>
</a>
<a>
    <b>21cm</b>
    <f>you</f>
</a>
<a>
    <d>22cm</d>
    <e>hello</e>
</a>
<a>
    <c>14m</c>
    <f>hi</f>
</a>
```

Now I would first need to transform theses numbers in a similar unit (lets say in `cm`) before I can sort them and find the maximum number. How can I do that?

I used the following XSL for my previous problem but now I need to update it so that I am able to transform my numbers before sorting them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="a/b | a/c | a/d">
        <xsl:sort select="." order="descending"/>   <!-- find the unit and transform it in centimeters before sorting -->
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <highest><xsl:copy-of select="."/></highest>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note:** I am using XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have adapted the answer of Dimitre Novatchev in here ([xslt sort output xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630259/xslt-sort-output-xml)).

If you apply the following stylesheet to your input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ext">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="letters" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="unsorted">
            <root>
                <xsl:for-each select="root/a/*">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="string(number(translate(., $letters, '')))!='NaN' and translate(current(), '0123456789', '') = 'cm'">
                            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                                <xsl:attribute name="oldvalue"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="number(translate(., $letters, ''))"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="string(number(translate(., $letters, '')))!='NaN' and translate(current(), '0123456789', '') = 'm'">
                            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                                <xsl:attribute name="oldvalue"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="number(translate(., $letters, '')*100)"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="string(number(translate(., $letters, '')))!='NaN' and translate(current(), '0123456789', '') = 'in'">
                            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                                <xsl:attribute name="oldvalue"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="number(translate(., $letters, '')*2.54)"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="string(number(translate(., $letters, '')))!='NaN' and translate(current(), '0123456789', '') = 'px'">
                            <xsl:attribute name="oldvalue"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="number(translate(., $letters, '') div 37.795275591)"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </root>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="vPass1" select="ext:node-set($unsorted)"/>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="$vPass1/*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <highest><xsl:copy-of select="."/></highest>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it outputs:

```
<root>
    <highest>
       <c oldvalue="14m">1400</c>
    </highest>
</root>
```

Comment: +1 I assume that you meant "adapted" - sorry for being nit-picking.

Comment: Most of it went above my head so tell me if i understood it right :p . So basically you created a new node-set from transformed numbers and then ran the `xsl:sort` on this new node-set. But wouldn't it amount to creating a copy of almost the whole input document and not to mention running a for-loop on the whole XML twice? Wouldn't it be very inefficient?

Comment: also why did you sorted the xml while creating the node-set?

Comment: I forgot to delete the `sort` there sorry, as it is only sorting the original nodes, not the processed nodes. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I suggest you go with Tim's advice. If I have time later, I'll try to do that.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Thanks for the edit. Have I typed "adopted" there? :D

Answer (score 4):

Do you like crazily complicated expressions? As an example, suppose you only had the units "m", "cm" and "mm" to consider, you could write your sort expression like this....

```
<xsl:sort select="number(translate(., 'cm', '')) * 
                  (
                     (translate(., '1234567890', '') = 'mm') * 1 + 
                     (translate(., '1234567890', '') = 'cm') * 10 + 
                     (translate(., '1234567890', '') = 'm') * 1000
                  )" 
          order="descending"/>
```

This takes advantage of the fact in a numeric expression, true is evaluated to 1 and false to 0. In this particular case it is converting everything into millimetres for doing the sort.

This avoids having to use a node-set, but that's probably the only thing you can say in its favour.....

Comment: +1. Thanx Tim. Your answer would work perfectly with the XML in my question, however my real XML is a lot more complicated than this because it contains more than one number in each tag and each of those numbers can have different units. A single numeric expression was proving to cumbersome to manage. I uploaded a simplified version of my real problem to avoid scaring of people :p